# Issues with VPS provider limiting CPU usage with data processing Spring Boot application

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, java, database, springboot

I developed a Java Spring Boot application with a PostgreSQL database. Since the data being processed is quite a lot, the processing can take time and it uses a lot of CPU (e.g. up to 100% obviously). My VPS provider automatically locks the server when the CPU is exceeded for a longer period of time.

I tried various solutions, such as `nice` with the lowest priority for starting the Java application or `cpulimit` on `postgres` instances or `java` instances, but using `cpulimit` seems to cause problems with the app itself, either Java won't start up or PostgreSQL won't finish processing the workload. `nice` however doesn't seem to prevent the "excessive" CPU usage, therefore the server still got shutdown/locked.

I'm not sure whether I need to optimize the application more (but I already did) and how I can avoid exceeding the CPU usage without causing problems with data processing.

The server has 2 GB RAM and 1 core how it seems.

Comment: What kind of provider shuts off a service for processor usage? It's easy to throttle this activity. Get a different VPS.

Comment: @GregAskew: It's vpsserver.com, they seem to be pretty big in that business. It's a shame they have this policy which is a huge inconvenience for customers.

Comment: Pretty big in the $5/month hosting. It's a junk service that can shut you off at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Applications not starting, and database queries not finishing, are severe problems with getting work done. If they can be traced to CPU quotas, you have a capacity planning challenge.

Find out what resources your provider claims this host has, and whether the technology is a VM or container. Very likely they oversubscribe CPU, so your legit workload bursts to most of a CPU could be a problem for them. Also ask the provider if this locking up event this happens is due to shortages of shared CPU, or some kind of penalty they impose.

nice, cpulimit, system resource control, none of these priority and quota systems will save you if the application sometimes requires more than available CPU time to perform acceptably.

Move to another hosting provider, to escape being starved of shared CPU, and to evaluate your options in general.  Adjust CPU and memory until it performs adequately. Even during burst usage such as start up or any batch processing. Try one host with 2 CPUs, try separating the database and application onto different 1 CPU hosts.

As this is a systemd Linux distro, enable resource accounting on the units per `man systemd.resource-control`.  Consider collecting detailed host metrics such as with [netdata](https://www.netdata.cloud/open-source/). Improve your analysis beyond that you hit 100% CPU. What fraction of this was application, versus database, versus other overhead? Does Linux pressure stall information indicate actually being stalled on CPU?

There will be other limiting factors to performance. For example 2 GB of memory is not a lot for an application and its database, but it might work for a small one. Look at host metrics to find memory pressure, especially around when the application is slow.

Answer (score 0):

Of course a solution is to move to a provider that doesn't lock the server when CPU is high. However, if you find the period of time that you shouldn't exceed, you can perhaps split the data in chunks that will be processed in a way that you won't exceed the period of time each time.